# SplitString SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

The below Split function works well. But it changes the order of my input.
Please help me to get desired output.

With respect to http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/85943/Split-function.

Input

```
SELECT * from dbo.fnStringSplitter('1,3,2', ',')
```

Expected Output

```
1
3
2
```

NOT

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: why is your expected output 1, 3, 2?

Comment: You pass 1,2,3 and you want 1,3,2. I guess you are changing the order not split string function

Comment: Edited by Question. Please work and getback. It is reasonable Question only

Comment: That is actually the worst performing splitter you can find. A loop is horribly inefficient for this type of thing. Check out this article for much better splitters. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Order by to get the result in required Order try changing the Split string function like this

Try this way

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Fnstringsplitter (@string    NVARCHAR(MAX),
                                      @delimiter VARCHAR(2))
RETURNS @result TABLE(
  id        INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
  split_val NVARCHAR(MAX))
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @start INT,
              @end   INT

      SELECT @start = 1,
             @end = Charindex(@delimiter, @string)

      WHILE @start < Len(@string) + 1
        BEGIN
            IF @end = 0
              SET @end = Len(@string) + 1

            INSERT INTO @result
                        (split_val)
            VALUES      (Substring(@string, @start, @end - @start))

            SET @start = @end + 1
            SET @end = Charindex(@delimiter, @string, @start)
        END

      RETURN
  END
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT split_val
FROM   dbo.Fnstringsplitter('1,3,2', ',')
ORDER  BY id
```

**Note:** This is not a efficient way to split the data. But reliable in your case

Comment: This seems good. I will test and mark it as answered. I need as function. you have hardcorded. Give it as function

Comment: @jamir - Updated check now

Comment: need one more help. check  Question i have asked in  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35102631/sql-server-update-in-ordering-fashion

Answer (score 0):

Datasets within SQL are inherently unordered.  When you require an explicit order you must explicitly request/create it.  This can be done using the [ORDER BY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx) clause or via code in your front end.